# Как получить значение столбца с максимальным значением в другом столце?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

```
df = pd.read_csv("out.csv", parse_dates=["Date"])
d = df.loc[df["Date"].dt.month == 1].groupby(df["Date"].dt.day).max()
```

Часть вывода:

```
14   2014-01-14     418
15   2014-01-15     468
16   2014-01-16     509
```

Нужно получить день 16 т.к значение максимальное.

Comment: какой вывод у `print(d.dtypes)`?

Comment: ```Date      datetime64[ns]

Berri1             int64```

Comment: Пожалуйста измените название и тест вопроса так, чтобы было явно понятно, о чем речь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.nlargest()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
res = d.nlargest(1, columns=["Berri1"])
```

если нужно получить значение индекса (`16`):

```
res = d["Berri1"].idxmax()
```